# multiquery count sql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a script using SUM that counts all the items ordered so Product 1 has been order 6 times and Product 2 has been ordered 9 times. Now in a seperate table (where I get the orderid from) there may be a bonus code. If this bonus code is a product (checked from other table) then I need to also add that to the count.

It's fairly odd to explain. Here is my code.

```
$query = "SELECT productid, SUM(quantity) FROM `order` GROUP BY productid"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $prodname = fetchproductname($row[productid]);
    echo $prodname ." - ". $row['SUM(quantity)'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

I need to know if there is a way I can store all of those results, then query the bonus codes, get the item number (if there is one) and add it to the totals. I've tried a few different queries and methods of playing with the while statement but coming unstuck.

I'm using 4 tables, Order (product id & quantity etc), Products (contains product name), Dispatch (contains a bonus code), Bonus (contains the productid)

Sample Data
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j27X.png

Comment: can you add sample sample data and desired result?

Comment: use a stored procedure to fetch the quantity of the product.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the complexity, but it sounds like you just need to query your bonus codes from within your product loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $prodname = fetchproductname($row[productid]);
    $productCount = $row['SUM(quantity)'];
    // Now query the bonus codes (you can come up with a better query probably, but this gives the idea)
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(bonus_code) bonus_count FROM dispatch d WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bonus b WHERE b.code = d.bonus_code AND b.productid = $productId)";
    $bonusresult = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($bonusRow = mysql_fetch_array($bonusresult)) {
        $productCount += $bonusRow['bonus_count'];
    }
    echo $prodname ." - ". $productCount;
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's probably better than mine, because you don't have to iterate over the entire bonus array.

Comment: Hi, i am not quite sure im understanding your solution. Its the sql query that is confusing me. Can you pls take a look at the sample data. As I basically start with dispatch - get ordernum & bonus code, the nquery the orders and bonus, then query the product name etc

Comment: When I can I'll look at your structure. You already might be able to come up with a better query to get the count of bonuses used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, all you have to do is store the results in an associative array. After you get the result:

```
$product_array = array();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $prodname = fetchproductname($row[productid]);
    $product_array[$prodname] = $row['SUM quantity'];
}
```

Then iterate over your Bonus table the same way, and for each bonus you find, add one to the relevant array:

```
[...]
if(isset($product_array[$bonus_product_name]))
    {
    $product_array[$bonus_product_name] = $product_array[$bonus_product_name] + 1;
    }
else
    {
    $product_array[$bonus_product_name] = 1;
    }
```

Finally, just iterate over the product array to print out the values

```
$keys = array_keys($product_array);
foreach($keys as $key)
    {
    echo("$key - $product_array[$key]");
    }
```